# ¿Por qué me da un Warning "dead code" en el if?

Tags: java

Este es mi método:

```
public static InputStream conectarseUrlConCertificado(String aliasFirma, PeticionFiscalDTO peticion, Map<String,Object> params){        
    try{
        URL url = new URL(peticion.getUrl());
        
        byte[] postDataBytes = null;
        if(peticion.getUrl().contains(PeticionesConstants.URL_PRESENTACION_JSON)){
            postDataBytes = getPostDataBytesJson(params, peticion.getCodificacion());
        }else{
            postDataBytes = getPostDataBytes(params, peticion.getCodificacion());
        }
        
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(PeticionesConstants.KEYSTORE_TYPE, PeticionesConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
        ks.load(null, null);

        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(PeticionesConstants.SSL_CONTEXT);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(PeticionesConstants.KEY_MANAGER);
        kmf.init(ks, PeticionesConstants.KEY_MANAGER_INIT.toCharArray());

        final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];
        X509KeyManager km = new CustomX509KeyManager(origKm, aliasFirma);

        ctx.init(new KeyManager[] { km }, null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        
     
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
        conn.setRequestMethod(peticion.getMetodo());
        conn.setRequestProperty(PeticionesConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, peticion.getContenido());
        conn.setRequestProperty(PeticionesConstants.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        if(postDataBytes== null) {
            return null;
        }
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
        LOGGER.debug("conectarseUrlConCertificado: Información enviada en la petición " + peticion.getCodigo());
        return conn.getInputStream();        
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("conectarseUrlConCertificado: Error al enviar: "+ e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

En el `if ==null` me tira un warning que pone *dead code*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque postDataBytes nunca podrá valer null? Quizá sea por eso.

Comment: El como comenta @SuperG280, la condición de null nunca se va a dar y por eso te dice que la borres.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes este código:

```java
        byte[] postDataBytes = null;
        if(peticion.getUrl().contains(PeticionesConstants.URL_PRESENTACION_JSON)){
            postDataBytes = getPostDataBytesJson(params, peticion.getCodificacion());
        }else{
            postDataBytes = getPostDataBytes(params, peticion.getCodificacion());
        }
```

Eclipse debe estar detectando que las llamadas a los métodos `getPostdataBytesJson` y `getPotDataBytes` nunca devuelven null

Answer (score 1):

Para el compilador y el lint del idle esa variable ha sido inicializada como consecuencia del return statement en el método "getPostDataBytes"

Para que no se den estas circunstancias, java creó la api de "Optional", de esta forma un método que devuelve null como posible valor, no tiene una relación implícita de conocimiento por parte del programador.

Te recomiendo cambiar el return del método "getPostDataBytes" a Optional y hacer algo similar a:

```
if (!postDataBytes.isPresent()) { 
  return null;
}
```

Además, como consejo yo intentaría, si es necesario que sea así, añadir ese return null antes de cargar todos los certificados para ahorrar tiempo de procesamiento innecesario.